# JMS to receive message- MQ Error code 2024 - message from queue are not getting removed

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, ibm-mq

I am using websphere application server 8.5

I have tried to recieve the messages from queue.The queue may contain multilple messages. I want to read all at once.

I recive the error WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2024' ('MQRC_SYNCPOINT_LIMIT_REACHED') though I read messages.

1. Should I call session's commit() method? If so  where should I call inside while loop for each message or outside the while loop?
2. createQueueSession(true, 0): Will there be any corrections in the arguments to be passed in this method in both Producer and consumer end?

**Approach:**

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;

public class Receiver
{
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/ConnectionFactory")
    private static QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(lookup = "jms/Queue")
    private static Queue queue;

    public void readQueueMessages() {                                                                   
        try {
            // create a queue connection
            QueueConnection queueConn = connFactory.createQueueConnection();

            // create a queue session
            QueueSession queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(true, 0);

            // create a queue receiver
            QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);

            // start the connection
            queueConn.start();

            // receive a message
            while(true) {
                TextMessage message = (TextMessage) queueReceiver.receive(180000);
                if (message != null) { 
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        // print the message
                        System.out.println("received: " + message.getText());
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch(JMSException exp) {
            // Handle this exception
        } finally {      
            if(queueConn != null) {                                                     
                // close the queue connection
                queueConn.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The queue manager has a parameter `MAXUMSGS` which is the maximum uncommitted messages for any client, this defaults to a value of `10000`.  When you receive `MQRC_SYNCPOINT_LIMIT_REACHED` this means that you have reached that limit.

Typically you would commit once you have processed the message, in your example this would be after printing it out.  Since all persistent messages are written to disk and disk can slow things down, you can tune for performance by committing multiple messages at one time.  Keep in mind that if your program crashes before the messages are committed they will be rolled back to the queue and processed the next time you start your program, because of this you would likely want to limit the number of uncommitted messages.

---

Since you are using WebSphere Application Server you should consider using a MDB rather than write your own.  The MDB will connect to the queue and wait for messages, read them from the queue and dispatch them to your own `onMessage` Java method to process messages.

I did a search and here are a couple links that may be helpful and I'm sure you can find others that discuss how to setup a MDB:

1. Chris Andrews presented a session "[Using IBM WebSphere Application Server
   and IBM WebSphere MQ Together](https://share.confex.com/share/120/webprogram/Handout/Session12611/SHARE2013_UsingWASandWMQTogether.pdf)"
2. Craig St. Jean has a blog post "[WebSphere 8.5, MQ, Spring, and Message-Driven Beans! Part 1](http://www.craigstjean.com/2016/02/WebSphere-8-5-MQ-Spring-and-Message-Driven-Beans/)"

Comment: If I use JMS as mentioned in my post, you said the commmit should be normally after printing the messages as mentioned in my example. But in JMS how I can tune the performance by commiting multiple meesages at one time?

Comment: @AlagammalP the need to tune would really depend on the volume of messages you are processing and the speed of the underlying storage.  Storage speed can be a bottle neck for various reasons, for example if the underlying storage is being synchronously replicated to another site across the network.  When you issue commit the queue manager has to write to storage.  If you wait and commit 5 messages MQ only needs to make one write to disk to commit all 5 messages.

Comment: @AlagammalP Your example is going to exit the loop if there is no message for 3 minutes, you could keep a count of messages processed and commit based on that, for example to commit ever 5 messages or when the timeout expired, inside the loop commit if  `(count % 5) == 0` and outside the loop commit if `(count % 5) != 0`.

Comment: Do we need to commit even while reading/Consuming/getting messages from Queue using JMS API? Because while putting messages I didnt commit? Could it be because of those umcommitted messages while put?

Comment: You need to call commit whenever you use transacted session. It does not matter whether your putting or getting messages.

Comment: Any uncommitted put or get count toward the max for a client.  You also would be unable to get a message that was put but not yet committed.  When you close a QueueSession it will commit the outstanding messages.